# How to get rid of motd on a single user account?

Tags: linux, ssh

I know how to modify and how to get rid of motd in general, but the problem is, that I'm not allowed to sudo on my school's server - and I'd like to get rid of a quite long motd that appears each time I ssh the machine. Is there any way to turn motd off only for my user-account without using sudo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution in polish wikipedia and in fact it's quite easy. The solution is to create empty `~/.hushlogin` file.

Comment: For reference, this is documented in the `login(1)` man page.

Comment: Well... the `man login` on my boxes here says that the home directory is checked for the hushlogin file, but not what it is actually for. Nice find, anyway.